# Difference between Vectored Interrupt Controller and Nested VIC

Tags: arm

I am newbie to micro-controller. Could some please throw more light on this?

I am trying to understand the fundamentals of Interrupt controller and Interrupt tables.

Comment: Possibly, one is a general concept of handling interrupts and the other is a specific implementation of that concept found in the ARM Cortex-M architecture (guessing from the tag), but you'd really need to be a lot clearer about the exact context and what specific details you actually want to know. At the moment this looks like a vague "please explain all of <large and complicated concept> to me" question, which are never good or on-topic.

Comment: Specifically i wanted to know what the word Nested stands for?